# curl doesn't work with #

Tags: php, curl

so I have this function which send a sms message, The function works great but the problem is when I send a # or a new line , the function doesn't work as expected !

```
function sendSMS($phoneNumber,$message){
$ch = curl_init();

$urll = "http://www....com/api/sendsms.php?username=username&password=pass&message=$message&numbers=$phoneNumber&sender=sender&unicode=E&return=full";
  $url = str_replace(' ','%20',$urll);
// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
}
```

if I use it like this for example :

```
sendSMS("phone number","#hashtag");
```

it doesn't send the message , whereas when I use it like this :

```
sendSMS("phone number","some text message");
```

it will send the message without any problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [`urlencode()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) every string you use in your url; particularly your message:

```php
$url = "http://www...com/api/sendsms.php?...&message=".urlencode($message)."&numbers=".urlencode($phoneNumber)."&...";
```

This will replace the `"#"` with `"%23"`. You already sanitize the space in your code by replacing it with `"%20"`, but that's not the only special character in an url string. So don't try to do this manually and let `urlencode()` do this work for you.